# Postgres Count number of items in an array jsonb fields

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table like this

```
activity

comment    likes
Hi         ["bill", "susan"]
Hello      ["susan", "john", "joe"]
```

I'm trying to get the total number of likes.

Likes is of type `jsonb`

I know I could select all the data and then loop through it with an increment and count it, but that would create performance issues once you get a lot of data.

Is there a way to do it with a single query?

For the above example, the total number of likes should be `5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @dassum was close, I just needed to adjust it to support jsonb

`SELECT SUM(jsonb_array_length(likes)) FROM activity;`

Comment: sorry, I missed jsonb. the good thing is your issue got resolved.